# TFS 2015 Can not Complete Pull Request

Tags: tfs, pull-request

I am setting up Pull Request in TFS 2015 GIT Repo. My Users are able to Create Pull Request however I am the only one that is able to Complete a pull request. I have confirmed that all the Users have Contribute to the entire repo. I am at a loss as to what is going on. Once the User Approves the PR and Clicks Complete Pull Request  the Button is disabled but it never starts the Merge Process. If the User refreshes the page the Complete Pull Request Button is active again. All of this works fine for me just not any of my other users so I assume it is a permissions issue but can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, you could complete your pull request after the reviewers approve of the changes by selecting Complete in the upper right of the pull request view.

[image]

*Complete button on the pull request view with its drop-down options*

After you selected the complete button, it will complete the pull request now and merge the changes to the target branch.

For permissions, you just need to grant **Contribute** permission of **target branch** (Pull Request: source branch into target branch) to the corresponding user.

Double check the permission settings, if they are added in some group deny the corresponding permission. In TFS, Deny trumps Allow.

Also make sure your pull request have **met all branch policy** before the completion.

Pull requests can be completed if the number of required approvals is met, even if other reviewers have rejected the changes.